# Find elements in a vector of tr1::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, stl, find, shared-ptr

I've wrapped my custom type 'MyType' in a smart pointer:

```
tr1::shared_ptr<MyType>
```

and made a vector from it:

```
vector<shared_ptr<MyType>>
```

Now I want to `std::find` an object of type `MyType` in that vector but can't since the type I'd need would be `shared_ptr<MyType>`.

Is there an elegant way?
Thank you

Update: Why not std::find_if: The usage of std::find is pretty compact. I thought implementing a method or functor for find_if would be a too large overhead.

Comment: you can define operator "==" for shared_ptr<T>, but the only elegant way, not polluting the code is to use find_if

Comment: The only way is to use find_if. Quote from here (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp) - `Note that the comparison operators for shared_ptr simply compare pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared.`

Comment: The way to do it with the standard library is to use `find_if`. What can't you use that?

Comment: Sorry; I’d really like you to explain *why* you don’t want to use `find_if`. Since it’s the correct solution here just throwing that remark out there isn’t helpful.

Comment: You could also make a heterogeneous `operator==`, between `shared_ptr<MyType>` and `MyType`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Heterogeneous comparison operators are a maintenance nightmare, because you also want the left/right symmetry of ordinary comparison, and you have to worry about implicit conversions etc.

Comment: @rhalbersma: If you expect me to argue in favor of them, you'll be disappointed.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Wasn't looking for an argument here, just pointing it out for the poster as well since he was looking for an elegant way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idiomatic and elegant way to do what you want is:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyType>> v;

// init v here;

MyType my_value;

// init my_value here;

auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<MyType> const& p) {
    return *p == my_value; // assumes MyType has operator==
});

if (it != v.end()) { /* do what you want with the value found */ }
```

If you can use `std::vector` and `std:shared_ptr`, you are obviously using the STL already. So why not use `std::find_if`? If you can't use C++11 lambda expressions, you can always use a function object.

Comment: Cool, thank you, that was helpful. Was not aware that I could use lambda expressions. Sry for the dont-want-find_if comment. I did not want to use find_if because it seemed to me that writing comparison method / functor would not be much more compact then looking up the value by myself. But your solution works and is really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To answer just the questions you posted, disregarding your aversion for find_if:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyType>> myVector; 
/* ... */
MyType const& whatIAmlookingFor = /* ... */;
auto ptr = std::find_if(begin(myVector), end(myVector), [&](std::shared_ptr<MyType> const& current)
{
  return *current == whatIAmLookingFor;
});
```

Now about you not wanting to use find_if "for some reasons" (what reasons might that be?):
You are looking for an elegant, STL/boost way to do something, but don't want to use the elegant, STL way to do it? Doesn't sound right.